# In a vanilla Rails 3 app, which objects are not thread safe i.e. have serialized access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a generic Rails 3 application that uses mysql, what parts of the framework are not thread safe?

I belief the actual sql connection to the database is serialized?  If not that I guess I read something incorrectly.

What areas are not thread safe?  Or rather are global references that all requests might share?

Comment: Congrats on hitting 1500 questions ;)

Answer (score 2):

All of Rails has been thread safe ever since the [2.2.2 release](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_2_release_notes.html#thread-safety).